# GetHashCode for a pair of playing cards C#

Tags: c#, gethashcode

I have a playing card class with the GetHashCode method implemented as follows:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   return (int)rank * 4 + (int)suit;
}
```

I now want to design a GetHashCode method that works for a 2 card hand/pair of cards. I thought something like this should work:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return (card1.GetHashCode() * 53) + card2.GetHashCode();
}
```

However, I would like the hashcode to be equal irrespective of the order of the cards. e.g. if card1 = Ace of Spades, card2 = King of Clubs the hashcode should be equal to that when card1 = King of Clubs, card2 = Ace of Spades.
I'm now thinking perhaps I could order the cards before applying my function but wondered if anybody can suggest a nice simple approach to this. Thanks

EDIT: Would this work?

```
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            if(card1.GetHashCode() > card2.GetHashCode())
            {
                return (card1.GetHashCode() * 53) + card2.GetHashCode();
            }
            return (card2.GetHashCode() * 53) + card1.GetHashCode();
        }
```

Comment: Yes that would work (the edit), but I would put the hashcodes in variables to avoid having to calculate it multiple times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using .NET Core/Standard 2.1 or later, the [HashCode struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=net-5.0) provides some nice helpers to avoid custom calculation code, which is [discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0070).

Example leveraging `HashCode.Combine()` for this use case:

```
public class Card
{
    public Card(int suit, int rank)
    {
        Suit = suit;
        Rank = rank;
    }

    public int Suit { get; set; }

    public int Rank { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(Suit, Rank);
}

public class Hand
{
    public IList<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public Hand(IList<Card> cards)
    {
        Cards = cards;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = new HashCode();
        foreach (var card in Cards)
        {
            hash.Add(card);
        }

        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems it would work, if anything I'd increase the possbile values to account for joker cards, or possible other cards.